# sort in hasMany relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I have 2 model POST and Member , I want order by lastname from member

but its return with default sort

```
$post= POST::where('type','<>',0)
       ->with(['member'=>function($query){
        $query->orderBy('lastname','desc');
       }])->paginate(10);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `members` must have been sorted based on what you have written, but not `posts`.

Comment: @Aa Aaa i think your code is working perfect `(i tried)`

Comment: @JigneshJoisar  its not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$post= POST::where('type','<>',0)
   ->with(['member'=>function($query){
    $query->latest('lastname')->first();
   }])->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `join()` or `leftJoin()`:

```
$posts = POST::select('posts.*')
    ->join('members', 'members.id', '=', 'posts.member_id')
    ->where('posts.type','<>',0)
    ->orderByDesc('members.lastname')
    ->paginate(10);
```